# How can i implement button.setOnClickListener and button.setOnTouchListener simultaneously

Tags: android

i am working on android.

i am creating a login button. i want that whenever i press login button then text color of that button should be changed.

and when this button pressed then login functionality should be performed.

for this i am coding like this:-

```
button_login.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int action = arg1.getAction();
    if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {                          
          button_login.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#163D74"));
          return true;
    } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
          button_login.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                  return true;
    }
         return false;

    }
 });        
button_login.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

    @Override

        public void onClick(View v)
            {
    // checking the functionality of login

             }
           });
```

but only onTouchListener is working. login functionality is not working.

please suggest me what mistake i have done. and how can i implement these both functionalities. means how can i change the color of text of button and how can i perform login functionality.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just declare your login functionality when action is UP.

```
button_login.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override

        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            int action = arg1.getAction();

            if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                  button_login.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#163D74"));

                return true;

            } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                   // check logine functionality.
                  button_login.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));

                return true;


            }

            return false;

        }

    });
```

Its does the same thing with the same logic.

Answer (score 1):

In [onTouch](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html#onTouch%28android.view.View,%20android.view.MotionEvent%29) method, you used  `return true;` that means

> True if the listener has consumed the event, false otherwise.

So you need to `return false` if you need it to consumed by other listeners

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is to change the UI state of button while pressing. For that you don't have to implement on touch... Just write an xml and put it on the src tag of button.

A. Create a new tag on colors.xml.. You can add colors as drawables.... which you will need on step two.

Write something like this in colors.xml

```
<drawable name="red">#0000ff</drawable>
```

B. Create a new xml in drawables folder, Name it what you like

write this in the xml, Here you can replace drawables here with drawable you can create with help of step A.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/android_pressed"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/android_focused"
          android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/android_normal" />
</selector>
```

This code is copied from [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html).. See `Custom Button` section.

C. Add this XML you created in step B as value of src attribute of your button, you have replaced of what I understood your onTouch is doing...